# Unity Font Metrics counting ascent for dymaic fonts

Tags: fonts, unity-game-engine, fontmetrics

I want to custom render font, but how to calc ascent for dynamic font for other size?

Using **Font.ascent** I receive only ascent for current setted size.

**On image:**
**1 step** - Without shifting;
**2 step** - Shift on char height;
**3 step** - shift on ascent - to font baseline;
[image]

Comment: I worked on a project that used custom font rendering a LOT; we tried to research how this works or how this is supposed to work, but ended up just picking the right values with trial and error. May be it become more stable or documentation became better in the later versions of Unity, but you may have to resort to just guessing the correct values, unfortunately.

Comment: Now I am counting ascent like this  Mathf.CeilToInt(_TargetFont.ascent * ((_FontSize / (float)_TargetFont.fontSize))); But this value is not exactly.